# How to access one class method from another class in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to dart. Currently, working on a mobile app through flutter. I have a `Helper` class which has some common methods which I've planned throughout the app. I've included that `Helper` class in another class. But, can't able to fig. out how to access its methods.

My commom `Helper` class code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Helper {

  Map userDetails = {};
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  // --- Method for getting user details from shared preference ---
  Future<Map>getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference () async {
    try {
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

      if(prefs.getString('user') != null) {
        this.userDetails = json.decode(prefs.getString('user'));
      } else {
        print('Shared preference has no data');
      }

    } catch (e){
      print('Exception caught at getUserDetails method');
      print(e.toString());
    }

    return this.userDetails;
  }

}
```

Here is my main program code where I've included the Helper class & trying to access it's `getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference ()`. In this case, I'm getting an error like `Only static memebers can be accessed in initializers`. I also tried to `extends` Helper class in `UserProfile` class. But, there also I'm getting a different kind of errors. Can't able to identify how to do this thing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'helper.dart';

class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    UserProfileState createState() => new UserProfileState();
}

class UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
    Helper helper = new Helper();
    var userData = helper.getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference();
}
```

@Günter Zöchbauer I've made my `Helper.dart` file like this as you've suggested -

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Helper {

  Map userDetails = {};
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  static Helper _instance;
  factory Helper() => _instance ??= new Helper._();

  Helper._();

  // --- Method for getting user details from shared preference ---
  Future<Map>getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference () async {
    try {
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

      if(prefs.getString('user') != null) {
        this.userDetails = json.decode(prefs.getString('user'));
      } else {
        print('Shared preference has no data');
      }

    } catch (e){
      print('Exception caught at getUserDetails method');
      print(e.toString());
    }

    return this.userDetails;
  }

}
```

Now, in my tryint to access that `getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference()` method I'm getting the same error `Only static memebers can be accessed in initializers` .

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could ensure a singleton instance of the class using a public factory constructor with a private regular constructor:

```
class Helper {
  static Helper _instance;
  factory Helper() => _instance ??= new Helper._();

  Helper._();

  ...
}
```

If you call `new Helper()`, you'll always get the same instance.

You need to import the file that contains `class Helper {}` everywhere where you want to use it.

`??=` means `new Helper._()` is only executed when `_instance` is `null` and if it is executed the result will be assigned to `_instance` before it is returned to the caller.

**update**

`getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference` is `async` and can therefore not be used in the way you use it, at least it will not lead to the expected result. `getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference` returns a `Future` that provides the result when the `Future` completes.

```
class UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
    Helper helper = new Helper();
    Future<Map> _userData; // this with ??= of the next line is to prevent `getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference` to be called more than once 
    Future<Map> get userData => _userData ??= helper.getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference();
}
```

If you need to access `userData` you need to mark the method where you do with `async` and use `await` to get the result.

```
  foo() async {
    var ud = await userData;
    print(ud);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm getting your intention what you wanted to say. After, including the ```Helper``` file how I can access the Helper calls method? Dose anything like ```Helper helper = new Helper(); var userData = helper.getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference();``` will help me to access the class as I've already done in my sample code or something else I need to do?

Comment: Seems I missed that part in your question. What doesn't work?

Comment: If you see my 2nd sample code in my post, the way I'm trying to access ```helper.getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference();```, is that right way to do or I need to make some modification in that?

Comment: The problem seems to be with `getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference` returning a `Future`. I updated my answer. See also https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: You also get the error message (your screenshot) because you can't access another field from a field initializer. The class-level fields can only be accessed when the constructor body is executed (or later), but not before, because otherwise it wouldn't be known if the initialization of all fields is already completed.

Comment: After updating with your updated code now Android Studio not showing any error. I think it'll work now. One more thing, if I need to update the Helper instance copy with updated data... how can I do that?

Comment: Setting `_userData` to `null` causes `??=` to execute the code again. `_userData = null; var ud = await userData;`

Comment: Then, I feel whenever I'll update my shared preference data of user I need to execute this once  ``` _userData=null;get userData => _userData ??= helper.getUserDetailsFromSharedPreference();```  . So that, Helper Singleton instance will repopulate it's userData copy from Shared Preference data. Am I right?

Comment: The helper singleton currently doesn't hold any data, currently only `Future<Map> _userData;` does.

Comment: Yeah, initially... Helper Singletop doesn't hold any data. But, after executing more than one time it'll hold a copy of data(user's shared preference data). Then, that will be a constant copy which I can access from any other place also. But, if at any point in time user update their shared preference data with a new data... at that time I need to update Helper Singleton copy also. So that, from wherever places I'm accessing Singleton data I'll always get an updated copy without doing any other things.

Comment: You can add a `dropCache()` method to reset the value and cause a 2nd access to actually load the data again.

Comment: Ok. Let me test this. Maybe after that, I can able to get more clarity in the whole thing. Thanks for patience to go through my questions & trying to helping me out. :)

Answer (score 7):

To access other class method you can simply put `static` on the method.

```
class Helper {
  static printing(String someText){
    print(someText);
  }
}


void main() {
  Helper.printing('Hello World!');
}
```